# python fastapi can't create multiple variation object in database for parent product

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I am trying to create multiple size and color for each of my parent product. when sending post request using fastapi swagger docs getting error

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "variations",
        0
      ],
      "msg": "value is not a valid dict",
      "type": "type_error.dict"
    }
  ]
}
```

**here is my code**

```
class Variation(BaseModel):
    size: str = None
    color: str = None
   
@dataclass  
class Product():
    title: str  = Form() 
    variations: List[Variation] = Form() 

@router.post("/main_product", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def create_main_product(product: Product = Depends(),current_user:get_current_user = Depends() ,db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
   
  
     create_parent_product = models.ParentProduct(
            product_title=product.title
     db.add(create_parent_product )
     db.commit()
     db.refresh(create_parent_product)
     for variation in product.variations:
        variation_str = f"size:'{variation.size}',color:'{variation.color}'"
        varitaion_product = models.VariationProduct(parent_product_id = create_parent_product.id,variations=variation_str) 
        db.add(varitaion_product)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(varitaion_product)
```

Comment: You can't use a nested class when using Form arguments - you'll have to use a JSON body in that case. What does the request you're making look like?

Comment: @MatsLindh my request look like` {title:"product_title",variation:[{'size':'xx','color:'red'},{siize:xl,color:'blue'}]}`

Comment: That won't map to a Form request, so you're going to have to use a JSON request and not `Form` in that case (just leave out `Form` and you'll get automagic matching to JSON).